# Как исправить ошибку несовместимости процессоров?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, unity3d, uwp

При создании пакетов игры на Visual Studio 2015 выходит это ошибка "there was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built amd64". Игра была создана на компьютере программиста с процессором AMD64 кажется. У меня хотя и архитектура процессора x64, выдает ошибку на несовместимость x86. Как исправить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196549/6104996   поможет?  только вам в другую сторону

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку у вас приложение на c# то вероятнее всего, что нет специфичного кода под конкретную платформу. Просто зайдите в свойства (каждого) проекта и выставьте тип платформы в AnyCPU.

Открываете Configuration Manager и для каждой конфигурации (Debug, Release, возможно ещё какие-нибудь будут) проставляете платформу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]